# Console output while using Websocketpp

Tags: c++, websocket, websocket++

I'm debugging some foreign code, which uses websocketpp. I keep getting quite verbose console output, although everything works fine.
Can I disable the output or does it at least point to something specific?
BR,
Daniel

```
[2014-07-08 14:51:27] [fatal] error in handle_read_handshake: End of File
[2014-07-08 14:51:27] [fatal] error in handle_read_frame: End of File (websocketpp.transport:7)
[2014-07-08 14:51:27] [info] asio async_shutdown error: system:10054 (An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)
[2014-07-08 14:51:27] [error] Underlying Transport Error
[2014-07-08 14:51:27] [fatal] error in handle_read_frame: End of File (websocketpp.transport:7)
[2014-07-08 14:51:27] [info] asio async_write error: system:10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine)
[2014-07-08 14:51:27] [fatal] error in handle_write_frame: Underlying TransportError
[2014-07-08 14:51:35] [fatal] error in handle_read_frame: End of File (websocketpp.transport:7)
[2014-07-08 14:51:35] [info] asio async_shutdown error: system:10054 (An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)
[2014-07-08 14:51:35] [error] Underlying Transport Error
```

Answer (score 8):

```
websocketpp::server<websocketpp::config::asio> server;

server.clear_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::frame_header | websocketpp::log::alevel::frame_payload); 
// this will turn off console output for frame header and payload

server.clear_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::all); 
// this will turn off everything in console output
```

More details can be found here:
http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/reference/logging

Comment: The link is stale.  [This link](https://docs.websocketpp.org/reference_8logging.html) might be more current.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a valid ip and port of running socket.io server

ie. if your socket io server running on local server you should give

`connect("http://localhost:8080")`

this might be helpful to others with same problem